# Error iframe html characters

Tags: html, iframe, encoding

excuse my English I speak Spanish

I'm trying to display multiple php and mysql registration, after that the show in an iframe

the problem is that apparently in the iframe shows me errors accents and other characters for example: for example (�D�nde cuesta menos y se consume m�s?")

this is what shows (�)

In the original query or first does not show me that, but in the iframe shows me that error

What should I do?

regards

Answer (score 0):

"When a browser renders/parses a web document that does not have the character encoding declared it will guess at what character set to use and may choose the wrong one therefore rendering the web page incorrectly."

Does the page in the iframe declare its encoding in its HTML?

Comment: apology not understand how declaring its encoding?

Comment: if you put them on and I get the same:

http-equiv="content-type" <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

iso-8859-1

nignuno of the 2 I work

Comment: sorry I don't understand that comment

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was write `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in `<head>`, but if you prefer (I don't think so) you can change all the accents with &(vocal)acute; like `&aacute` (á).

You can find all the special HTML characters [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).