# Error with characters in a html iframe

Tags: php, mysql

excuse my English I speak Spanish

I'm trying to display multiple `php` and `mysql` registrations which will be shown inside an iframe.

the problem is, iframe shows me errors for special characters such as: accents, exclamation marks, etc for example (�D�nde cuesta menos y se consume m�s?")

This is what shows: (�)

In the original query or first does not show me that, but in the iframe shows me that error.

I tried with `http-equiv = "content-type" <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: is your file created as a `UTF-8`?

Comment: also you said in the meta it is a php, but those tags there are html, try setting the headers of the php file to utf-8

Comment: Since you tagged this as `mysql`, make sure your DB is also UTF-8 compliant.

Comment: Hey, do not get in the database is fine, shows me right in the original page, the problem is the iframe

Comment: @dinerobeta Then make sure that your iframe file is saved as UTF-8 and not ANSI. May also be a byte order mark issue.

Comment: Make sure your database is with utf-8 encoding too. Check your mysql connection properties, as they should utf-8 too. Same for table and columns colations. By default mysql uses swedish colation(?!?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error iframe html characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622832/error-iframe-html-characters)

Comment: Why 4 times the same question?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not in the files to display in the frame, may be the problem in the data.
I always try to configure PHP, Apache and MySQL with UTF8.
For this, I edit some configuration files.

**MySQL:** /etc/my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-client=utf8
character_set_results=utf8
```

Then:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

**PHP:** /etc/php.ini

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

**Apache:** /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Then:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

Another thing to consider when connecting to the database:

```
...
$link = mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
...
```

---

You can see all characters related variables using:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%';

+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci            |
| completion_type          | NO_CHAIN                   |
| concurrent_insert        | AUTO                       |
| connect_timeout          | 10                         |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

---

You must make sure that the page displayed in the iframe tag has also:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

I hope it helps somewhat.

Comment: You can see all characters related variables in MySQL using: show variables like 'c%'; I edit my answer.