# Iframe html does not allow space characters

Tags: php, iframe, mysqli

Hi all I have a problem with an iframe which shows me no special characters

but the result page where I show me the sample data very well

but in the iframe is the problem

and place meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  and is still the problem

this is the website where sample data:

http://foronet.net/temas.php

Here is where the right iframe

http://foronet.net/index.php

I agracezo your help

regards

Comment: This is the 3rd question for the same problem within a 4 hour period. Stay with your initial question. You received many comments and answers. It's up to you to find the answers in already posted questions and Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with characters in a html iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623959/error-with-characters-in-a-html-iframe) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622832/error-iframe-html-characters

Answer (score 0):

For temas.php, Chrome automatically detected your encoding for the page as "Turkish". For index.php, Chrome says "UTF-8".

Save your file with "UTF-8" encoding, and add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`.

In Chrome, you may have to un-check auto detect encoding, then check it again, for it to reload the encoding. (Menu (Three bars) > Tools > Encoding > Auto detect).