# how could I automatically update a query php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a php mysql query, what I want is that actualize automatically each time you enter a data and not have to do it for the browser

this is the query in php:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$consulta ="SELECT subject,tid,username FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 15";  
    $resultado = mysql_query($consulta) 
echo "<table  border='0'><td>";
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
 echo "   <div >
     <a target='_parent' href='showthread.php?tid=".$fila['tid']."'> " . $fila["subject"] ."</a></td><tr><td>Por: " .$fila["username"]."</div><br>"; 
    } 
echo '</td></table>';
mysql_close($enlace);
?>
```

How could I do that automatically actualize?

regards

---

excuse is that I speak Spanish almost do not understand the English

if you update data automatically

Comment: What does "actualize" mean?

Comment: I think he means "update". :P

Comment: excuse is that I speak Spanish almost do not understand the English


if you update data automatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error iframe html characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622832/error-iframe-html-characters)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the query to be executed automatically each time there is new data in your table or database. Meaning, if you get new information in the table "mybb_threads", you want the user to see this new data without updating the browser.

To achieve this you need to work with Javascript, and something called Ajax. Bascally what you do is that every minute or whatever, you force the browser to call a php file.

You can read more here about the jQuery .ajax() function which is a great place to start:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can also check out the Wiki that explain the method quite good:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)